# P&T: which approach to take with app constantly creating new tables

Tags: select, performance-tuning, table, oracle-19c

A customer is complaining about low performance.
No cpu or memory bottlenecks observed on the system.
The problem is that their app is constantly creating new tables that are used for a while, then remain unutilized.
This causes query plans to be always quite bad.

I believe i tried everything:

- checking system resource for leaking: no.
- no error in alert log
- punctual tuning on each query: useless, they keep coming and they're always a little different.
- since queries are always on a different table, setting cursor_sharing=force isn't useful
- gathering stats on the entire schema isn't helpful enough: performance degradation keeps on coming every 1-2 weeks.
- AWR do not show anything interesting other than "Execute to parse %" very low and "DB CPU"&"sql elapsed time" very high.

Which approach do you suggest me to take in this kind of situation?

Thank you.

Comment: There's not enough detail here to say for sure, but sounds like an application redesign is in order. Possibly using a single partitioned table rather than always creating new ones? Are there a lot of inline functions in their queries or subqueries? Things that would drive up CPU as the number of rows increases, without affecting I/O or other performance parameters?

Comment: @pmdba Unfortunately the customer can't edit the application code. Most of the queries consist of multiple select and nested selects: I believe that the massive number of session (which are executing those extractions) is the cause of the cpu workload.